# Additional information: The remote server returned an unexpected response: (413) Request Entity Too Large

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm getting this error in my WCF Service: Additional information: The remote server returned an unexpected response: (413) Request Entity Too Large.

I tried to increase maxReceivedMessageSize to 2147483647 but it still doesn't work. Then, I measured the size of my file and I realized that it has 10 Kb.

Do you guys have any idea of what it might be?

I'm sending you a copy of my code:

Here, I'm basically sending a list of 1o Kb for the business logic layer (WCF service)

```
  else if (comboBoxReason.Text == "Antecipação indevida - automática")
            {
                AdjustmentAmount = 0;

                using (Stream s = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                    formatter.Serialize(s, AnticipationAdjustment); 
                    long size = s.Length;
                }



                AdjustmentAmount = Decimal.Round(FinancialAdjustmentsCalculations.AnticipationAutomaticRate(AnticipationAdjustment), 2); //THE ERROR IS HERE
                textBoxAdjustment.Text = ValorAjuste.ToString();
                AnticipationAdjustment.Clear();
            }
```

That is my Web.Config from the Business Logic Layer (Ext)

```
  <bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IInt" closeTimeout="01:00:01" openTimeout="01:00:01"
             receiveTimeout="02:00:01" sendTimeout="09:00:00" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
             maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"/>
  </basicHttpBinding>
```

And that is my App.Config from the interface:

```
         <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IExt"
      closeTimeout="01:00:01"
    openTimeout="01:00:01" receiveTimeout="02:00:01" sendTimeout="09:00:00"
    maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
```

I tried to add the readerQuotas and maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647", but it still doesn't work:

```
              <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IExt" closeTimeout="01:00:01"
    openTimeout="02:00:01" receiveTimeout="01:00:01" sendTimeout="09:00:00"
    maxBufferPoolSize="524288000" maxBufferSize="65536000" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536000">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:56296/ExtService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IExt" contract="ExtService.IExt"
            name="BasicHttpBinding_IExt" behaviorConfiguration="Behaviors.EndpointBehavior"  />
    </client>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Behaviors.EndpointBehavior">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Have you tried increasing the values for <maxDepth> in <readerQuota> section? Something like that (for testing purposes only) <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />

Comment: Additionally, you could try setting maxItemsInObjectGraph as described in [devlicio.us](https://web.archive.org/web/20150424012546/http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2010/05/04/setting-maxitemsinobjectgraph-for-wcf-there-has-to-be-a-better-way.aspx)
Something like this to the serviceBehaviour on both client and server side <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646"/> and

Comment: I tried that man, but it is not working :( (I edited the post with this trial)